Image.full won't display anything, image and image.value display a low resolution image from dataverse in powerapps gallery
I have a gallery of images in a Powerapps canvas app from a dataverse data source. The images all display in the gallery. When a user clicks/taps on one of them I want it to go to a new screen showing the high-res version of the image. I've done this with a previous app and it seems all the settings are the same, I can't figure out what is going wrong with this one. I have two apps pulling from the same table and both have the same issue. When I click on the image in the gallery, it sets a variable varThisPhoto to the ThisItem record Set(varThisPhoto,ThisItem) then navigtes to a screen where I want to display the full res image, I set the image property of the image control to varThisPhoto.ThisImage and it displays the low resolution version, if I set it to varThisPhoto.ThisImage.Full it is blank, no errors, just blank. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

In the table, under advanced options, I would sweep across the checkboxes with my mouse cursor and mistakenly thought that I had a check in the checkbox for "Can store full images". I haven't tested it yet, but I am fairly certain this will fix my issue
